# Running code generated in realtime in JavaScript with eval()

Tags: web-browser, javascript

Consider a front-end JavaScript application where menu items needed to be shown or hidden based on somewhat simple logic (roles that user has and some other logical state).

A simple language was introduced to define this logic in a concise human-readable way and every menu item was assigned a string condition, which looks like this: `"isLoggedIn() AND NOT role(PARTNER)"`.

In order to actually check this condition, a simple compiler was implemented, which translates this language into a valid JavaScript code string and executes it using `eval()` returning the boolean result in the end.

The compiler works by replacing some constructs, like `AND`, `OR` and `NOT` with valid JavaScript equivalents like `&&`, `||` and `!` using simple regular expressions:

```
private compileExpression(expression: string) {

  // Adding commas around function arguments (to make them strings)
  expression = expression.replace(/(\w+)\((.*?)\)/g, `$1('$2')`);

  // Replacing "AND"
  expression = expression.replace(/\sAND\s/g, ' && ');

  // Replacing "OR"
  expression = expression.replace(/\sOR\s/g, ' || ');

  // Replacing "NOT"
  expression = expression.replace(/(\s|^)NOT\s/g, ' !');

  // Prefixing predicates
  expression = expression.replace(/(\w+)\((.*?)\)/g, 'Π.$1($2)');

  return expression;

}
```

This turns `"isLoggedIn() AND NOT role(PARTNER)"` into `"Π.isLoggedIn() && !Π.role('PARTNER)"`, which is then executed by `eval()`:

```
public matchCondition = (condition: string): boolean => {

  // Using greek letter "P" for predicate (for shortness and uniqueness)
  // noinspection NonAsciiCharacters
  const Π = this.predicates;

  const expression = this.compileExpression(condition);

  const result = eval(expression);

  return result;

}
```

The `Π` is an object with simple predicate functions, which return boolean values like `isLoggedIn(): boolean` and `role(roleName: string): boolean`.

The expressions, that are being translated and executed are stored statically in local object as strings and are not accessible from global context. Also, all expressions are written by the developers and are not coming from users of the application in any way.

Is it safe to use `eval()` this way or should it be avoided at all costs (e.g. "eval is evil", "never use eval", etc)?

What are the possible attack vectors, that could be used to compromise such eval usage?

If expression strings will be loaded from the HTTPS server using XHR/Fetch, will it change the situation security-wise?

The reason to introduce such language and not defining the rules in code directly is that it required that these conditions could be defined in string values, e.g. in a JSON file. The other reason is that such language is easier to read at a glance.

Comment: It's not just that eval is potentially insecure (which it is), it's also that solutions relying on `eval` are typically hard-to-follow, confusing, and impossible to debug when things break.  There are nearly always solutions that are, in all ways, better.

Comment: The alternative solution would be to write a full-fledged interpreter for this meta-language, which will take a lot of additional (complex) code, which must by tested and maintained. And I'm practically sure that it will be even harder to debug. So I'm not sure that avoiding `eval` in this scenario will be "always better".

Comment: I mean, I don't know your exact use-case, but I really doubt you have to go so far as building an entire language to make this happen.  I suspect you're over thinking it.  I've built a rules engines that allow the user to fully configure detailed conditions that have to be met before taking arbitrary actions, and did so without requiring either eval or a meta-language.  In fact my rules engine sounds much more complicated.  Things like: "If this is the customer id, and the status is one of these, and it was created more than X days but less than Y days ago, then send this email and this text

Comment: I suppose I can't exactly break down a new system for you in comments, but effectively my answer is "I think you're using the wrong approach and should come up with a different solution".  Eval is rarely the answer.

Comment: I think any attacker using the Development Tools to change `isLoggedIn` to `true` might break things on your side. Check if an unauthenticated user can access the function by knowing the URL. Client-side validation is no real validation.

Comment: @ThoriumBR by changing anything through the Developer Tools, the "attacker" will only break it's own client. This will not affect other users or the back-end of course. And the menu items are no secret by itself.

Comment: I do wonder why your developers are not writing javascript straight away. Your syntax doesn't seem to have that much of a conciseness and readability advantage, but the regular expression compiler is very limited.

Comment: If all you are doing is to hide and show menus, why not use CSS selectors instead of Javascript?

Comment: If you want to keep your regular expressions, consider using `\b` instead of `\s` or `(^|\s)`.

Comment: In what was can the developers writing these rules preview, validate, or otherwise test that they are written correctly? Are the menu items being shown and hidden for security or user convenience? I don't think it's *just* the use of `eval()` that can be risky.

Comment: @SlavaFominII the regex based language will also require significant testing. What if a string literal contains the letters "AND"? What if there are two predicates (so `.*` matches everything between the open bracket of the first, and the close bracket of the last)? You have written a language interpreter, whether you intended to or not, and the process of fixing bugs in it will likely either gradually turn it into one that looks like the complex one you're attempting to avoid writing, or turn it into an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: I tend to think you are trying to solve the wrong problem, wether these lines can be set with a configuration, come from database or anything, why aren't these instructions not made server-side, while returning only the appropriate tabs according to permissions? Note that hiding the tabs would not be enough if the HTML is still in the DOM, people can view them via dev tools..

Comment: Seems to me that you're proverbially reinventing the wheel, here. There are major free javascript libraries available that handle exactly this sort of thing, plus a lot more, and using one of them instead of making your own would most likely be easier, more secure, less prone to bugs, and take less of your time. My preferred one is [Angular](https://angular.io/docs).

Comment: If you use `eval()` for a virtual function you cannot turn it off with a Content-Security-Policy. This reduces the hardening possible. A was around this would be generating a policy script from the Mets language server side.

Comment: I agree with Conor. I think that while this is an interesting concept, it actually lacks creativity in solving whatever problem you're trying to solve with it. There are better ways. (Think enums, functions stored in variables, object mapping, etc.) Especially in JavaScript, too, with such easy creation of anonymous functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "*front-end* Javascript application"? A web page? A web application written in server-side Javascript?

Comment: Using regex is not a good idea. You can use library like `esprima` to parse the code to AST and validate that if you really need to.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Using `eval` in this context doesn't create any vulnerability, as long as an attacker can't interfere with the arguments passed to `matchCondition`.

If you find it easier to read / program it this way, and you're confident that no untrusted input will ever go into your expression compiler, then go for it.

**`eval` isn't evil, untrusted data is.**

---

Please note that it's entirely possible to avoid `eval`, by extracting the predicates then handling them with your custom functions, for example:

```
if (predicate === 'isLoggedIn()') {
    return Π.isLoggedIn();
}
```

Comment: The code in my question is not even trying to somehow sanitize the passed expression, I guess this is obvious. I believe the main question is how would attacker put `alert\`1\`` (or any other malicious code) into the expression in the first place?

Comment: Oh, I missed the "all expressions are written by the developers" part. Edited my answer.

Comment: Another alternative for replacing it `return Π[predicate]();` where the passed in predicate is the string `"isLoggedIn"`. You can validate it, of course, to avoid a TypeError when running the code or to avoid any potential other situations but there is very rarely a good reason to use `eval` especially if all you need is to call some function dynamically. In JS you can also pass *functions* as parameters, so it's entirely possible to do that instead of a string and execute it at the end.

Comment: Although I realize this is infosec.SE and what the OP is doing isn't necessarily insecure, `eval` is still evil for plenty of other reasons.

Answer (score 32):

Today, everything is written by developers. Next month or next year, someone will say "hey, why not let the users write those themselves?" Bam.

Also, even if the rules are written by the developers only, do they or will they include any user-originated data? Something like titles, names, categories, for instance? This could quickly lead to an XSS attack.

Your regular expressions are so "open" (using lots of `.*` without any validation) that if anything untoward gets in, it will slip through directly to the `eval` in a minute.

At the very least, if you want to keep `eval`, you should have a lot stricter expressions instead of `.*`. But those can quickly become either difficult to understand, or a hindrance for many practical cases.

Comment: The point regarding the future proofing makes sense, thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the rules are written by the users, or by professional devs, all that matters is whether you offer unsanitised data/code to _other_ users. In the majority of cases, `eval` is fine, because a malicious actor can only affect code that he is running himself.

Comment: I think you give developers too much credit here! :)

Answer (score 6):

### Appearances and expectations

If something looks like a safe expression, people will probably treat it like one. If a field looks like any other data-field, people (even developers) will probably put untrusted data in there. If something is evaluated with full level application access, it should look and feel like code.

Another problem are subtle bugs in your pre-compiler, which could introduce unwanted bugs/security flaws. Most vulnerabilities start with unwanted bugs, before a malicious attacker can exploit something. And a new meta-language without proper vetting/tests and strongly defined syntax is just another layer of confusion and bugs waiting to happen.

If only developers write code for your conditions, why not just use plain JavaScript? The meta-language brings hardly any benefit. And code is handled by people like code.

Answer (score 5):

Front-end javascript itself is completely at the will of the client running the code.  **If you are depending on front-end javascript for security, you've already failed to secure your application**.  Forget eval.  The client can replace your entire website with their own implementation if they desire.  Thus, your server should validate **everything** that the client asks it to do.

In your case, you should ask yourself if it's a security violation for users to see menu items that they're not privileged enough to see.  If so, then the server  should *not* deliver those menu items to the client, because users can look at any javascript you deliver to them.  If not, then you don't have any security concerns at all -- as others have mentioned, eval is only "bad" if it is run against unsanitized code.  Since your eval'd code is currently sanitized, then I don't believe you have security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, as long as your rules really are coming only from trusted developers, there shouldn't be any security holes from using `eval`.

However, `eval` has plenty of other disadvantages, in terms of complexity, maintainability, debuggability, etc. And using regular expressions plus `eval` could easily result in problems down the road, depending on how your application grows.

I also think it's possible that you're overestimating the difficulty of writing your own interpreter; open-source libraries are mature enough that you can create a pretty nice interpreter even if (like me) you're not well-versed in parser and compiler implementation. Here's a grammar for [PEG.js](https://pegjs.org/) that I put together in about 15 minutes based on your problem description. For demonstration purposes, it just returns the predicate names; to use it, you'd change it to return a function that takes the predicates object and invokes the appropriate predicate, but hopefully this is enough to give you an idea of one possible approach.

```
OrExpression
  = head:AndExpression tail:(_ ("OR") _ AndExpression)* {
      return tail.reduce(function(result, element) {
        return result || element[3];
      }, head);
    }

AndExpression
  = head:NotExpression tail:(_ ("AND") _ NotExpression)* {
      return tail.reduce(function(result, element) {
        return result && element[3];
      }, head);
    }

NotExpression
  = "NOT" _ expr:NotExpression { return !expr; }
  / "(" _ expr:OrExpression _ ")" { return expr; }
  / Predicate;

Predicate
  = _ predicate:[A-Z]+ _ "(" _ arg:[A-Z]* _ ")" {
        return predicate.join('') + '(' + arg.join('') + ')';
      }

_ "whitespace"
  = [ \t\n\r]*
```